# output of map adds byte order marks to the xml

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-mapper

I have a map which builds me a message, which then gets passed to another map (all in an orchestration.

Inspecting the message output from the first map I can see that the message contains EF BB BF byte order marks.

When the 2nd map executes, it throws an exception "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 61.":

> xlang/s engine event log entry: Uncaught exception (see the 'inner
>   exception' below) has suspended an instance of service
>   'MyCompany.MyOrchestration(004464ca-1c34-e342-591d-5e8182a4be18)'.
>   
> The service instance will remain suspended until administratively
>   resumed or terminated.  
> If resumed the instance will continue from its
>   last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
>   
> InstanceId: 62d99333-8dc4-4ca4-9e5b-7fdf8583e081 Shape name: conCDA
>   
> ShapeId: ba722b56-c115-4abb-b40c-211824369266 
> Exception thrown from:
>   segment 1, progress 15 
> Inner exception: Data at the root level is
>   invalid. Line 1, position 61.
>            
> Exception type: XmlException 
> Source: System.Xml 
> Target Site: Void Throw(System.Exception) The following is a stack trace that
>   identifies the location where the exception occured
>
> at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)    
> at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)    
> at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()    
> at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()    
> at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()   
>  at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)    
> at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean
>   preserveWhitespace)    
> at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader
>   reader)    
> at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(TextReader txtReader)   
>  at
>   Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Service.Transform.ShredXmlDocument(Stream
>   inStream, Object[] outParams, String mapName, XmlDeclaration xmlDecl) 
>   
>  at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Service.ApplyInMemoryTransform(Type mapRef,
>   TransformMetaData trfMetaData, Object[] outParams, Stream[] inStreams)
>   
> at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Service.ApplyTransform(Type mapRef, Object[]
>   outParams, Object[] inParams)    
> at
>   MyCompany.MyOrchestration.segment1(StopConditions
>   stopOn)   
>  at
>   Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment s,
>   StopConditions stopCond, Exception& exp)

How do I get the first map to not add the byte order markings?

**Edit:**
The first map is a map that has two messages on the input side that map to a singme message out the output side.  The first message maps all nodes using link by structure, and the second messages uses a mass copy functiod.  I can't see any funny character at character 61, even when viewing the message at the byte level.  I can see the BOM, which is why I was thinking that was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that this is a BOM issue - you have not made it clear how you are creating your map (i.e. do you have custom functiods, are you using XSLT etc.) Can you confirm what character is on (or around) character 61 - is it one of the [Reserved Xml Markup Characters](http://www.w3resource.com/xml/reserved-markup-characters.php)?

Alternatively, have you checked that the 1st map you invoke produces valid output when run using the 'Test Map' tool in VS Solution Explorer? Do you have the 'Validate TestMap Input' and 'Validate TestMap Output' options set to TRUE and it doesn't throw any errors? Also, have you tried saving the output from the 1st map test and using it as input to the 2nd map test?

Comment: The first map is a map that has two messages on the input side that map to a singme message out the output side.  The first message maps all nodes using link by structure, and the second messages uses a mass copy functiod.  I can't see any funny character at character 61, even when viewing the message at the byte level.  I can see the BOM, which is why I was thinking that was the issue.

Comment: The BOM characters *might* be causing issues and pushing characters out to the 61st char, but I've never come across this before. What happens if you strip the BOM off the output and try that using the test map functionality?

Comment: You were right!  this wasn't a BOM issue.  The problem was that a namespace change in one of my schemas caused the custom xslt used in my map to output non xml content.  The error was actually on the output of the map (not valid xml) not on the input message.

Comment: Are you happy to mark this as the answer or update your original question to include the fix?